# <mat-radio-button> : No value accessor

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material2

I have this HTML:

```
 <mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button  [(ngModel)]="searchType">
      And (Narrower search)
  </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button  [(ngModel)]="searchType">
       Or (Wider search)
  </mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group>
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
>   attribute

I tried using this instead:

```
 <mat-radio-button name="search-and"[(ngModel)]="searchType">
      And (Narrower search)
 </mat-radio-button>
```

and I get this error:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with name:
>   'search-and'

so then I tried this:

```
 <mat-radio-button value="search-and" name="search-and" [(ngModel)]="searchType">
              And (Narrower search)
 </mat-radio-button>
```

and this:

```
  <mat-radio-button [value]="search-and" name="search-and" [(ngModel)]="searchType">
              And (Narrower search)
  </mat-radio-button>
```

and I still get this error:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'search-and'

Answer (score 12):

Try to set `formControlName="SearchType"` on `<mat-radio-group>` and not on `<mat-radio-button>`.

Comment: That was my problem. I was setting the `formControlName` on each `<mat-radio-button>`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Angular Docs not very intuitive https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

Answer (score 2):

Ugghh my bad, `ngModel` belongs at the parent level:

```
  <mat-radio-group fxLayout="column" [(ngModel)]="searchType" (change)="onSearchTypeChange()">
     <mat-radio-button value="search-and" name="search-and">
          And (Narrower search)
     </mat-radio-button>
     <mat-radio-button  value="search-or" name="search-or">
         Or (Wider search)
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
```

Now everything works, no errors, not sure whether to use `[value]` or `value` though.

Comment: It will depend on the value of value. If you set a string value in the template, then use value, i.e. value="Yes". If you use a property value, then use [value], i.e. [value]="data.value"